# read instructions from file python

Tags: python-2.7

I have this code:

```
import os
def inplace_change(filename, old_string, new_string):
    # Safely read the input filename using 'with'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
        if old_string not in s:
            print('"{old_string}" not found in {filename}.'.format(**locals()))
            return
        else:
        # Safely write the changed content, if found in the file
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                s = s.replace(old_string, new_string)
                f.write(s)

path = raw_input("Enter the file's full path: ")  
old = raw_input("String to change: ")
new = raw_input("change to: ")

print "********************************"
print "**** WORKING... PLEASE WAIT ****"
print "********************************\n"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    filename = os.path.join(path,file)
    inplace_change(filename, old, new)

os.system("pause")
```

As you can see, the code is replacing sub string in a file with another sub string. I want my code to change text as directed in a text file, like "instruction file" what to change.
The text file will be:

```
"old_string" "new_string"
"old_string" "new_string"
"old_string" "new_ string"
```

the result will be that all files in directory will change all the old_string to new_string

How can I do it?